# how to not repeat randint value

Tags: python, random

I just wrote a code to generate random numbers and try to match it with random numbers, but I don't know how to not repeat the randint value, can someone help me?

```
from random import randint
import time

first_time = time.ctime()
print  first_time

x = randint(1, 10000)
while x != randint(1, 10000):
    ran = randint(1, 10000)
    print ran
    x = ran

print 'You number is: ', x
print ('You stared at: '+first_time)
print ('You finished at: '+time.ctime())  
print('Finish')
```

Comment: So once you choose a random number, you want to make sure this random number isn't selected again?

Comment: What do you mean "not repeat the randint value"?

Comment: yes do you know how @rayryeng

Comment: i do not want to repeat the 'ran' variable @BrenBarn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest may be:

```
deck = list(range(1, 10001))
random.shuffle(deck)
```

and use `deck.pop()` to get the next "`randint` without repetition".

This is pretty much how you get a random card without repetition from a deck (which indeed the very name of `random.shuffle` suggests, and why I called the variable `deck`:-): you start with all cards in the deck, shuffle the deck once (thoroughly of course!-), then just deal the last card from the top of the deck each time, without putting it back in the deck.

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off Alex's solution, if you don't want to maintain a list of arbitrary length (for example, if you want a few hundred unique random ints in the range (0..a gazillion), then you instead have to maintain a list of numbers that have been chosen already:

```
numbers = set()
while len(numbers) < enough:  # enough is defined somewhere...
  numbers.add (random.randint(0, upper_limit))
```